# Luigi "tasks not granted run permission by the scheduler"

Tags: python, luigi

I'm trying to create Luigi tasks dynamically (based on attributes in cmdList) and make the preceding task the dependency of the next task. SQLTask is a subclass of Luigi.Task. However, when I run this code, I get `This progress looks :| because there were tasks that were not granted run permission by the scheduler`
What am I missing?

```
class BDX_Task(SQLTask):
    acctDate = luigi.Parameter()
    ssisDate = luigi.Parameter(default=None)
    queryKey = luigi.Parameter()
    queryCmd = luigi.Parameter()
    runDesc = luigi.Parameter()
    dependQry = luigi.Parameter()

    def run(self):
        print(subprocess.call(self.queryCmd, shell=True))
        self.get_target().touch()

def dep_s_dep(cmdList, dep1):
    """
        This returns dependency task's dependency 
    """
    dep2 = [(key,cmd,dep) for key, cmd, dep in cmdList if key==dep1]
    return dep2[0]

class BDX_Query_0XX(SQLTask):
    acctDate = luigi.Parameter()
    ssisDate = luigi.Parameter()  
    runDesc = luigi.Parameter()
    depend_task = ""

    def run(self):
        YY = self.acctDate[:4]
        MM = self.acctDate[4:6]
        acctDate = self.acctDate
        ssisDate = self.ssisDate
        runDesc = self.runDesc
        bdx_sql = r'r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\'
        cmdList = [
                ('BDX010',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_001_NI_DM 010.sql -o output010.txt',None),
                ('BDX020',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_001_NI_DM 020.sql -o output020.txt','BDX010'),
                ('BDX022a',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 010.sql -o output022a.txt','BDX020'),
                ('BDX022b',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql -o output022b.txt -v Year1={YY} MM={MM}','BDX022a'),
                ('BDX022c',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 030.sql -o output022c.txt -v Year={YY} Month={MM}', 'BDX022b'),
                ('BDX023',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_023_P031_MTD_All_Final_CatAdj.sql -o output023.txt ','BDX020'),
                ('BDX024',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_024_P031_ITD_All_Final_CatAdj.sql -o output024.txt','BDX020'),
                ('BDX025a',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 010.sql -o output025a.txt','BDX020'),
                ('BDX025b',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql -o output025b.txt -v Year={YY} Month={MM}','BDX025a'),
                ('BDX025c',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 030.sql -o output025c.txt -v YYMM={acctDate}','BDX025b')
            ]

        tasks = []
        for queryKey, queryCmd, dependQry in cmdList:
        class_name = queryKey

        klass = type(queryKey, (BDX_Task,),{}) # {'acctDate': self.acctDate, 'queryKey': queryKey, 'queryCmd': queryCmd, 'runDesc': self.runDesc, 'dependQry': dependQry})

        if dependQry != '':
            dep1 = dep_s_dep(cmdList, dependQry) # info about dependency task (key, cmd, dep's dep)
            print(f"{queryKey}'s dep1", dep1)
            depend_task = [globals()[dependQry](acctDate=self.acctDate,
                                                ssisDate=self.ssisDate,
                                                queryKey=dep1[0],
                                                queryCmd=dep1[1],
                                                runDesc=self.runDesc,
                                                dependQry=dep1[2])]

            def requires1(cls):
                return depend_task

            setattr(klass, "requires", classmethod(requires1))

        globals()[queryKey] = klass  # make the class available at the module level

        tasks.append(globals()[queryKey](acctDate=self.acctDate, ssisDate =self.ssisDate, queryKey = queryKey, queryCmd = queryCmd, runDesc = self.runDesc, dependQry = dependQry)) # this addes Task class named after queryKey to dependency
    yield tasks

        self.get_target().touch()
```

===========Stack trace

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe R:/1.PY/DataPipeLine/run_BDX_process.py BDX_Query_Main --local-scheduler
DEBUG: Checking if BDX_Query_Main(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if BDX_Query_9XX(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX_Query_Main_201904_201905_444c47aebc   has status   PENDING
DEBUG: Checking if BDX_Query_0XX(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1) is complete
BDX020's dep1 ('BDX010', '"r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_001_NI_DM 010.sql" -S LWVPDBSQLC070 ', '')
BDX022a's dep1 ('BDX020', '"r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_001_NI_DM 020.sql"  ', 'BDX010')
BDX022b's dep1 ('BDX022a', '"r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 010.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070 ', 'BDX020')
BDX022c's dep1 ('BDX022b', '"r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year1=2019 MM=04', 'BDX022a')
BDX023's dep1 ('BDX020', '"r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_001_NI_DM 020.sql"  ', 'BDX010')
BDX024's dep1 ('BDX020', '"r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_001_NI_DM 020.sql"  ', 'BDX010')
BDX025a's dep1 ('BDX020', '"r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_001_NI_DM 020.sql"  ', 'BDX010')
BDX025b's dep1 ('BDX025a', '"r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 010.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070 ', 'BDX020')
BDX025c's dep1 ('BDX025b', '"r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year=2019 Month=04', 'BDX025a')
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX_Query_9XX_201904_201904_Luigi_tes_201905_db874019d2   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX_Query_0XX_201904_201904_Luigi_tes_201905_db874019d2   has status   PENDING
INFO: Done scheduling tasks
INFO: Running Worker with 1 processes
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 3
INFO: [pid 6820] Worker Worker(salt=931855678, workers=1, host=LWVPWEACT001, username=i805649, pid=6820) running   BDX_Query_0XX(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1)
INFO: [pid 6820] Worker Worker(salt=931855678, workers=1, host=LWVPWEACT001, username=i805649, pid=6820) new requirements      BDX_Query_0XX(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1)
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
DEBUG: Checking if BDX010(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX010, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_001_NI_DM 010.sql" -S LWVPDBSQLC070 , runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX010_201904___r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_c7c8473ba5   has status   DONE
DEBUG: Checking if BDX020(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX020, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_001_NI_DM 020.sql"  , runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX010) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if BDX025b(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX025b, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year=2019 Month=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX025a) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX020_201904_BDX010__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_573b857d50   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX025b_201904_BDX025a__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_eef5a35ad5   has status   PENDING
DEBUG: Checking if BDX022a(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX022a, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 010.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070 , runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX020) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if BDX025b(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX025b, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year=2019 Month=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX025a) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX022a_201904_BDX020__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_7a4a9cc485   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX025b_201904_BDX025a__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_eef5a35ad5   has status   PENDING
DEBUG: Checking if BDX022b(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX022b, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year1=2019 MM=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX022a) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if BDX025b(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX025b, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year=2019 Month=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX025a) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX022b_201904_BDX022a__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_313dc66c50   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX025b_201904_BDX025a__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_eef5a35ad5   has status   PENDING
DEBUG: Checking if BDX022c(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX022c, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 030.sql"  -v Year=2019 Month=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX022b) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if BDX025b(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX025b, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year=2019 Month=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX025a) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX022c_201904_BDX022b__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_d198713a82   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX025b_201904_BDX025a__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_eef5a35ad5   has status   PENDING
DEBUG: Checking if BDX023(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX023, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_023_P031_MTD_All_Final_CatAdj.sql"  , runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX020) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if BDX025b(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX025b, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year=2019 Month=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX025a) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX023_201904_BDX020__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_236e57639e   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX025b_201904_BDX025a__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_eef5a35ad5   has status   PENDING
DEBUG: Checking if BDX024(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX024, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_024_P031_ITD_All_Final_CatAdj.sql" , runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX020) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if BDX025b(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX025b, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year=2019 Month=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX025a) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX024_201904_BDX020__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_1a8ad5a673   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX025b_201904_BDX025a__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_eef5a35ad5   has status   PENDING
DEBUG: Checking if BDX025a(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX025a, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 010.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070 , runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX020) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if BDX025b(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX025b, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year=2019 Month=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX025a) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX025a_201904_BDX020__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_91bd598abf   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX025b_201904_BDX025a__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_eef5a35ad5   has status   PENDING
DEBUG: Checking if BDX025b(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX025b, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year=2019 Month=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX025a) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX025b_201904_BDX025a__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_eef5a35ad5   has status   PENDING
DEBUG: Checking if BDX025c(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX025c, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 030.sql"  -v YYMM=201904, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX025b) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if BDX025b(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX025b, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070  -v Year=2019 Month=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX025a) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX025c_201904_BDX025b__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_c98f5f14c3   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX025b_201904_BDX025a__r__1_SQL_BDX_SQ_eef5a35ad5   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   BDX_Query_0XX_201904_201904_Luigi_tes_201905_db874019d2   has status   PENDING
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Done
DEBUG: There are no more tasks to run at this time
DEBUG: There are 12 pending tasks possibly being run by other workers
DEBUG: There are 12 pending tasks unique to this worker
DEBUG: There are 12 pending tasks last scheduled by this worker
INFO: Worker Worker(salt=931855678, workers=1, host=LWVPWEACT001, username=i805649, pid=6820) was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
INFO: 
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 14 tasks of which:
* 1 complete ones were encountered:
    - 1 BDX010(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX010, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_001_NI_DM 010.sql" -S LWVPDBSQLC070 , runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=)
* 13 were left pending, among these:
    * 1 were missing external dependencies:
        - 1 BDX_Query_0XX(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1)
    * 2 had missing dependencies:
        - 1 BDX_Query_9XX(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1)
        - 1 BDX_Query_Main(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905)
    * 10 was not granted run permission by the scheduler:
        - 1 BDX020(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX020, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_001_NI_DM 020.sql"  , runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX010)
        - 1 BDX022a(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX022a, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 010.sql"  -S LWVPDBSQLC070 , runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX020)
        - 1 BDX022b(...)
        - 1 BDX022c(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX022c, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 030.sql"  -v Year=2019 Month=04, runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX022b)
        - 1 BDX023(acctDate=201904, ssisDate=201905, queryKey=BDX023, queryCmd="r:\1.SQL\BDX_SQL\BDX_023_P031_MTD_All_Final_CatAdj.sql"  , runDesc=201904 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX020)
        ...

Did not run any tasks
This progress looks :| because there were tasks that were not granted run permission by the scheduler

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Firstly, dynamic dependencies are useful when the the full list of tasks isn't know until runtime. For example you might have a situation where you have to run a task to query a database, and for each row returned by your query you require a new dependency.

This is distinctly different use case from creating a set of tasks and their dependencies programmatically, which is what it feels like you are doing in your example.

The following toy code shows how you could achieve what you are trying to do:

```
import luigi
import datetime
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('luigi-interface')

task_list = {
    'taskA': ['taskA_command', ''],
    'taskB': ['taskB command', 'taskA'],
    'taskC': ['taskC command', 'taskA'],
    'taskD': ['taskD command', 'taskB'],
}

// Equivalent of your BDX_Task class
class MyTask(luigi.Task):

    task_date = luigi.DateParameter()
    task_name = luigi.Parameter()
    task_command = luigi.Parameter()
    dependent_task_name = luigi.Parameter()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyTask, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        logger.debug('MyTask.__init__ called for task_name="{}"'.format(self.task_name))

    def output(self):
        filename = 'output_files/{date:%Y%m%d}/{name}.output'.format(date=self.task_date,name=self.task_name)
        return luigi.LocalTarget(filename)

    def requires(self):
        if self.dependent_task_name != '' and self.dependent_task_name in task_list:
            dependent_task_command, next_dependent_task_name = task_list[self.dependent_task_name]
            return [self.__class__(
                task_date=self.task_date,
                task_name=self.dependent_task_name,
                task_command=dependent_task_command,
                dependent_task_name=next_dependent_task_name,
            )]
        else:
            return []

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as handle:
            handle.write('Command to run: "{cmd}"'.format(cmd=self.task_command))


// Equivalent of your BDX_Query_0XX class
class myWrapperTask(luigi.WrapperTask):
    task_date = luigi.DateParameter(default=datetime.date.today())

    def requires(self):
        for task_name, (task_command, dep_name) in task_list.items():
            yield MyTask(
                task_date=self.task_date,
                task_name=task_name,
                task_command=task_command,
                dependent_task_name=dep_name,
            )
```

Output generated

```
$ PYTHON_PATH=.:$PYTHON_PATH && python -m luigi --module dynamic_dependencies myWrapperTask --local-scheduler --log-level INFO
MyTask.__init__ called for task_name="taskA"
MyTask.__init__ called for task_name="taskB"
MyTask.__init__ called for task_name="taskC"
MyTask.__init__ called for task_name="taskD"
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   myWrapperTask_2019_04_12_c2195ac5bd   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   MyTask_taskB_taskD_command_2019_04_12_6afc23b3fe   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   MyTask_taskA_taskC_command_2019_04_12_35a27fe401   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   MyTask_taskA_taskB_command_2019_04_12_d66dc54b89   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   MyTask__taskA_command_2019_04_12_bdb7812ab5   has status   PENDING
INFO: Done scheduling tasks
INFO: Running Worker with 1 processes
INFO: [pid 35037] Worker Worker(salt=526551035, workers=1, host=ChrisPalmersMBP.localdomain, username=cpalmer, pid=35037) running   MyTask(task_date=2019-04-12, task_name=taskA, task_command=taskA_command, dependent_task_name=)
INFO: [pid 35037] Worker Worker(salt=526551035, workers=1, host=ChrisPalmersMBP.localdomain, username=cpalmer, pid=35037) done      MyTask(task_date=2019-04-12, task_name=taskA, task_command=taskA_command, dependent_task_name=)
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   MyTask__taskA_command_2019_04_12_bdb7812ab5   has status   DONE
INFO: [pid 35037] Worker Worker(salt=526551035, workers=1, host=ChrisPalmersMBP.localdomain, username=cpalmer, pid=35037) running   MyTask(task_date=2019-04-12, task_name=taskB, task_command=taskB command, dependent_task_name=taskA)
INFO: [pid 35037] Worker Worker(salt=526551035, workers=1, host=ChrisPalmersMBP.localdomain, username=cpalmer, pid=35037) done      MyTask(task_date=2019-04-12, task_name=taskB, task_command=taskB command, dependent_task_name=taskA)
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   MyTask_taskA_taskB_command_2019_04_12_d66dc54b89   has status   DONE
INFO: [pid 35037] Worker Worker(salt=526551035, workers=1, host=ChrisPalmersMBP.localdomain, username=cpalmer, pid=35037) running   MyTask(task_date=2019-04-12, task_name=taskD, task_command=taskD command, dependent_task_name=taskB)
INFO: [pid 35037] Worker Worker(salt=526551035, workers=1, host=ChrisPalmersMBP.localdomain, username=cpalmer, pid=35037) done      MyTask(task_date=2019-04-12, task_name=taskD, task_command=taskD command, dependent_task_name=taskB)
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   MyTask_taskB_taskD_command_2019_04_12_6afc23b3fe   has status   DONE
INFO: [pid 35037] Worker Worker(salt=526551035, workers=1, host=ChrisPalmersMBP.localdomain, username=cpalmer, pid=35037) running   MyTask(task_date=2019-04-12, task_name=taskC, task_command=taskC command, dependent_task_name=taskA)
INFO: [pid 35037] Worker Worker(salt=526551035, workers=1, host=ChrisPalmersMBP.localdomain, username=cpalmer, pid=35037) done      MyTask(task_date=2019-04-12, task_name=taskC, task_command=taskC command, dependent_task_name=taskA)
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   MyTask_taskA_taskC_command_2019_04_12_35a27fe401   has status   DONE
INFO: [pid 35037] Worker Worker(salt=526551035, workers=1, host=ChrisPalmersMBP.localdomain, username=cpalmer, pid=35037) running   myWrapperTask(task_date=2019-04-12)
INFO: [pid 35037] Worker Worker(salt=526551035, workers=1, host=ChrisPalmersMBP.localdomain, username=cpalmer, pid=35037) done      myWrapperTask(task_date=2019-04-12)
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   myWrapperTask_2019_04_12_c2195ac5bd   has status   DONE
INFO: Worker Worker(salt=526551035, workers=1, host=ChrisPalmersMBP.localdomain, username=cpalmer, pid=35037) was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
INFO:
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 5 tasks of which:
* 5 ran successfully:
    - 4 MyTask(task_date=2019-04-12, task_name=taskA, task_command=taskA_command, dependent_task_name=) ...
    - 1 myWrapperTask(task_date=2019-04-12)

This progress looks :) because there were no failed tasks or missing dependencies

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====
```

The major structural difference from your code is that that my `task_list` is defined outside the task classes. It's possible that you simplified things for SO, and that your `cmdList` is really going to be the output from another task and can't be defined outside the classes. You could solve that by just adding the list to `globals()` once generated or you could pass the full list of commands to `MyTask`/`BDX_Task` as a parameter so it can be referenced in `MyTask.requires()` (maybe not the best idea if the list is potentially large). Also, as you originally did, you couldn't use a `luigi.WrapperTask` like my example.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation. Really appreciate it!

Comment: How could I make the individual "MyTask" have its own name (ie. task_name) so that Luigid visualization doesn't show all of them as "MyTask" which make it hard to tell the status of each task.

Comment: I tried to change "yield MyTask(" to "yield type(task_name, (MyTask,),{})(" and dependency to "type(dependent_task_name, (self.__class__,),{})", but it gave me an error: _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'abc.BDX022a'>: attribute lookup BDX022a on abc failed

Answer (score 1):

I guess the line:
`Parameter "task_process_context" with value "None" is not of type string.`

Shows you some of your tasks are not retrieving the expected output.
In those cases luigi takes the task as not accomplished.

Make sure all tasks return the type defined (*in the following task*) as input.
In your case, `None` is breaking the pipelined execution, try to make sure those Tasks  return `str` in case they fail/have no data to return, instead of `None`.

Use an emtpy string `""` or a keyword string you use to hold the empty dependency: `"empty"`

Comment: Thanks. I changed None to '' as you advised. The `not of type string` warning is now gone, but I still get `tasks not granted run permission by the scheduler` message. Stacktrace has been updated above.